# CSS - How to working with multi-level menu by simple

Tags: html, css

I have a multi-level menu look like

[image]

I want my menu

- Has the same background (#5b740d as you see)
- Has the same active background (red as you see)
- Has the same hover background (red as you see)

And three above option will for all menu and sub-menu

But my code look like complex. Here is my example code for hover

```
/* hover: can using a simple selector to make all are same background */
.menu li:hover {
    background: red;
}
.menu li li ul li a:hover {
    background: red;
}
.menu li ul li:hover a {
    background: red;
}
```

I get the css on internet but it's complex then i change it by my way (**But it still complex :( plz help me make it simple** ). 

But i get bug: when i hover item (2) like in my picture bellow then item (3) was hover?

[image]

plz simplified my css code to do three option above (i don't understand complex code :( ) and help me fix my bug thank.

Here is my code **http://jsfiddle.net/SWF6w/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to make this more 'simple', there is very little superfluous markup or definitions in that code, so I don't really understand your appeal to make it more simple.

You can easily fix the red hover on child elements by specifying a direct descendent selector on your `li:hover a` selector, though. For example:

```
.menu li ul li:hover > a {
    background: red;
}
```

Will produce this result > http://jsfiddle.net/SWF6w/1/

Comment: i think that can more simple: I just edit something and only need `.menu li:hover {
 background: red;
}` here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/urybX/. I think if you design my idea from begin i think code is more simply. But i can't, anyone can help me thank

Comment: Sure, hire a developer. No-one's going to write it for free for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this piece of code :

```
.menu li li ul li a:hover {
    background: red;
}
.menu li ul li:hover a {
    background: red;
}
```

With this one:

```
.menu li li ul li>a:hover {
    background: red;
}
.menu li ul li:hover>a {
    background: red;
}
```

Here is updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SWF6w/2/

Comment: No need for the first change.